# What is the difference between me and mihi?

Tags: grammar-identification, word-usage, duolingo

I'm studying Latin on Duolingo and am trying to find out more about parts that I don't understand. One of those words is *me* and *mihi* because Duolingo and any other sites I check says they both mean "me" but seem to have a different usages like *salve* and *salvete*. So what is the difference?

Comment: Are you studying Latin? Do you have a Latin grammar or textbook? This is basic Latin grammar (*case* changing the meaning and function of pronouns).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to give a number of small answers, numbered for easy reference if they need discussion:

1. Duolingo has tips that explains some of the grammar. They're worth checking out even if nothing puzzles you in the exercises.
2. Duolingo is not great for developing understanding.
   It's a nice supplement to your toolbox if you want easy access to brief daily practice sessions, but it's not good at all as the only tool.
   If you want to properly learn any language on Duolingo, at least use a grammar (a grammar book) to get a more proper explanation of the things you are exposed to.
   There are good Latin grammars online, too.
   I would also suggest a textbook, but a free online reference grammar is a minimum.
3. Consider the English pronoun *I/me/my*.
   Why does it have three different forms?
   When do you use each?
   Their difference is one of **case**.
   Latin has more cases than English and they are not restricted to a few pronouns like in English, but the basic phenomenon is the same as with *I/me/my*.
4. *Me* is the accusative case and *mihi* the dative case.
   How each case is used is a long story better not told here.
   I'm sure the Duolingo tips will cover at least some basics of it, and a grammar will give more depth.
5. It's not directly related to your question, but I also recommend finding a free online Latin dictionary you like and using it.
6. There is a similar but different difference between *salve* and *salvete*, which is explained in the same material.
7. I'm glad to hear you're learning Latin and I hope you'll keep going.
   If you're puzzled by something, do ask more question here.
   But do try to solve things yourself first with the supporting material and tell us what you found and what is yet to be explained; that way the answers will be much more useful.
   (If you prefer, you may also ask questions in other languages than English.)
8. Browse this site.
   You'll pick a number of interesting things about Latin, some at your level and some more advanced.
   There are many great explanations around here.

Examples of online materials:

- [Our list of online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79)
- [Allen & Greenough's Latin grammar](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/alphabet)